# My desktop keeps hard drives on in sleep mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, sleep

When I put my PC in sleep mode, my SSD stays on. I see that the LED on SSD is still lighting in sleep mode and I also hear some other HDD or HDDs spinning. How can I set my PC to turn off not necessary things like the hard drive in sleep mode like my laptop and my other desktop does on W10? My MB is GA-945GCM-SL2.

Comment: Does your machine even have a mechanical HDD in it? Sounds like you want to suspend your machine if you want it to be silent.

Comment: Are these external drives? Often there's no way to tell the enclosure to spin it down.

Comment: There are internal 2 HDDs and SSD. I heard that one or both HDDs turns off on sleep mode but fan and SSD in which system is installed stays on.

Comment: Yes; An LED light would suggest this is an external SSD.  Question should be be clarified by using [edit] mechanism

Comment: @Pranciskus - While in a sleep state, your machine isn’t powered off, so it still generates heat.  This means fans must still be turned on.  If you want your machine in a powered off state, then suspend the machine, this will make the processor go into a specific power state. Hopefully you are not putting your laptop in a sleep state in a bag. Great way for it to overheat and automatically shutdown

Comment: SSD is connected with SATA cable and PSU cable is plugged into SSD. Is this called external? SSD itself has LED.

Comment: You might wish to / need to update BIOS and power driver, and then reset Power Power Properties and restart / test.

Comment: @John Thanks. My BIOS version is the latest. In BIOS I changed S1 (POS) to S3 (STR) and now my PC parts go to sleep.